# Converting from c to nasm assembly, how to fix all the DWORD PTR [rbp-5] type lines to make it work?

Tags: assembly, nasm

In converting from c to assembly and fixing the file to get it to run, I'm confused as to what the lines such as DWORD PTR [rbp-4],0 mean. I assume it's moving 0 into the register, but which one? Or how do I word it to get it to run?

For instance, I believe the following is supposed to be

```
if (choice != 'N' && choice != 'F' && choice != 'X'){
        printf("Invalid Input. Enter N, F, or X\n");
```

I have the "Invalid input..." line in the LC0 register. "je" means if false, jump to L3, so would it automtically jump after the first comparison?

```
L5:
    mov eax, 0
    call    menu
    ;mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-5], al
    ;cmp    BYTE PTR [rbp-5], 78
    je  L3
    ;cmp    BYTE PTR [rbp-5], 70
    je  L3
    ;cmp    BYTE PTR [rbp-5], 88
    je  L3
    mov edi, LC0
    call    puts
    jmp L2
```

Comment: `nasm` doesn't use the `PTR`, so just delete those so you get `mov BYTE [rbp-5], al` and such.

Comment: Deleting PTR on all of those lines gave me output! not the desired result, but on to figuring that out now!

Comment: It's not moving anything into the register.  It's using the register as a pointer to a memory location.  The `PTR` notation is superfluous.  Most assemblers do not require it.  That's more for you than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

`cmp    BYTE PTR [rbp-5], 78`

means that the byte value located at [rbp-5] is compared to the byte value 78.

Had it been `DWORD PTR` then instead dword-sized values would have been assumed on both ends.

No register is involved in this particular operation (well, other than the rbp frame register for the address).

To my knowledge, there is no `LC0` register. Was it supposed to have been a variable instead?